# Como criar duas conexões com banco de dados diferentes?

Tags: java, mysql, db2

Estou precisando passar dados de um banco (DB2) para o outro (MySQL), e estou pensando em como fazer isso, como no banco que tenho os dados não tenho acesso a algumas ferramentas, como fazer o *backup*, só posso fazer `SELECT`, eu pensei em fazer duas conexões com o *JDBC*, pegar os registros e já inseri-los no MySQL, tem como? Ou é melhor eu salvar em um *txt* e depois passar para o MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode abrir duas conexões com bancos de dados diferentes e então inserir os dados lidos de um banco de dados no outro mais ou menos assim:

```java
String urlMySql = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seu_database_mysql";
String urlDb2 = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/seu_database_db2";

Connection connMySql = DriverManager.getConnection(urlMySql);
Connection connDb2 = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDb2);

PreparedStatement selectDb2 = connDb2.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABELA");
ResultSet rsDb2 = selectDb2.executeQuery();

while (rsDb2.next()) {
    PreparedStatement insertMySql = connMySql.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO OUTRA_TABELA VALUES...");
    insertMySql.setXXX(rsDb2.getXXX(...));
    insertMySql.executeUpdate();
}
```

Daí, tudo o que você tem que fazer é gerenciar os `Connection`s, `PreparedStatement`s e `ResultSet`s como de costume (inclusive fechando-os em um bloco `finally` ou usando o `try-with-resources`).

Também é válido encapsular os `Connection`s em DAOs, colocar as conexões em pools ou separar qualquer operação com o banco de dados em várias classes e/ou vários métodos. Apenas tenha em mente que poderá haver mais do que uma conexão com o banco de dados ativa ao mesmo tempo (juntamente com os respectivos `PreparedStatement`s e `ResultSet`s).

Comment: Deu certinho, valeu! :D

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode ter um único `con` referenciando duas conexões de banco de dados. 
Você definitivamente precisa manter duas referências diferentes.

```
Connection con1 = DriverManger.getConnection( connect1 );  
Connection con2 = DriverManger.getConnection( connect2 );
```

Não há outra alternativa.

**Solution 1:** Criar multiplos metodos para retornar local e remota conexão.

```
public Connection getLocalConnection() {
  ...
  Connection localCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect1 );  
  ...
  return localCon;
}

public Connection getRemoteConnection() {
  ...
  Connection remoteCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect2 );  
  ...
  return remoteCon;
}
```

**Solução 2 :** Se você deseja gerar tanto conexão em cada chamada e devolvê-los, é melhor você usar um objeto da lista para voltar:

```
public List<Connection> createConnection() {
  ...
  Connection localCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect1 );  
  Connection remoteCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect2 );  
  ...
  List<Connection> connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>( 2 );
  connectionsList.add( localCon );
  connectionsList.add( remoteCon );
  ...
  return connectionsList;
}
```

Eu prefiro usar Solução 1 , porque as vezes você pode estar verificando alguns dados em um único banco de dados.

Comment: Solução muito boa mesmo. Mas como o que precisava era um pouco mais urgente, e mais gambiarrado a outra solução funcionou também. Valeu cara! +1